# How to output different file extension into different directories with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle

I want to output:

- All `.js` files into folder `js`
- All `.css` files into `styles`
- All media like a `.svg | .png | .jpeg` into 'assets' and so
  on.

My config https://jsfiddle.net/sicely/43w28stq/

Comment: You want the output to look like this? or your want the input to look like this?
if its the input i would say just look at all folders for .js and all folders for .css etc then just organize it the way you want.

Comment: @JamesHarrington I want the output looks like this. Now in my 'dist' folder any directories, but I want to split files by extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your webpack.config.js file:

**JS files**

```
  output: { 
            filename: './js/[name].bundle.js',    // prepend folder name
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            chunkFilename: './js/chunkFilename.[name].bundle.js'    // prepend folder name
     },
```

**CSS files:**

```
plugins:[ 
   new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash].css',  // prepend folder name
        chunkFilename: 'css/[name].[id].css',    // prepend folder name
        ignoreOrder: false,
    }),
],
```

**Images**

```
rules:[
  {       
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    outputPath: 'images'  // folder name
                }
            }],
        },
]
```

**Fonts**

```
 rules:[{  
       test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        outputPath: 'fonts'  // folder name
                    }
                }]
       }]
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I do all like you say. But now I have another problem. I have a 404 error because font path is wrong. Now is dist/font , but need dist/style/font . Can you help me one more time? https://jsfiddle.net/sicely/z8g5sr9e/