# How to put webpack output files in separate folders?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I looked through webpack documentation, but couldn't find answer to my question.

How can I put certain files for example in /dist/src/js and styles in /dist/src/styles ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up file name with specify path

examples with js in output

```
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[fullhash].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/chunk.[name].[fullhash].js',
```

Comment: It should be in rule of the test?

Comment: you can check this post for more information
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62220231/how-to-output-different-file-extension-into-different-directories-with-webpack